# MapboxGL dataloading event never change property isSourceLoaded to true

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to get the moment where my source is completely loaded to perform an action.
I am using [Map#dataloading](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#MapDataEvent) and waiting until `isSourceLoaded` becomes true, but this never happens.

I am using the listener like this:

```
map.on('dataloading', e => {
  if (e.dataType === 'source') {
    console.log(e)
  }
})
```

[and the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkMfK.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be listening to the `data` event, and not the `dataloading` event, but even so there is a bug with the implementation of `isSourceLoaded` that is being tracked here https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3958. In the meantime, a workaround would be checking for `map.style.sourceCaches["composite"].loaded()` when the `data` event fires.

Hope this helps!

*Disclaimer - I work at Mapbox*

Comment: Hello @mollymerp, thanks for your help.  
In the end, I managed this checking the state of the map calling  `map.loaded()` while is loading all sources and updating my application state when it returns true.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you did this? I really need to find a way, after zooming and panning, to make sure all features are rendered and it sounds like this is what you did.

Comment: Hello @malcolm, my context is a React application using MapboxGL. I extracted the piece of code that is checking if all sources are loaded and posted on this [link](https://gist.github.com/thiagoxvo/21fd8503e868745bf028ab48a346e7f5). I hope it helps.